# JAVA at one point i can't input anymore

Tags: java

The program works great but the problem is that at one point I can't input anymore. Sometimes it works sometimes it keeps getting stuck. For example here

```
Enter a number: 40
too big
Try again: 
20
too big
Try again: 
10
too big
Try again: 
5
to0 small
Try again: 
2
too small
Try again: 
6
```

Code:

```
package main;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ifelse {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int a, zufallszahl;
    zufallszahl = (int) (Math.random()*100 + 1);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    a = input.nextInt();
    if ( a == zufallszahl){
        System.out.println("        B        I       N        G         O        ");
    }
    while (a > zufallszahl){
        System.out.println("zu groß");
        System.out.println("Try again: ");
        a = input.nextInt();    
    }
    while (a < zufallszahl){
        System.out.println("zu klein boy");
        System.out.println("Try again: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: With your current logic, if you enter a number too small and then a number too large, you will end the program. Instead of two loops you need one encapsulating loop on all checks

Comment: It will only do each greater or less check once minimum. You need to keep running the greater then less then check. I would recommend changing those whiles to ifs and putting a while around them. Add another if checks if the number is the same and break if it is.

Comment: You need a while loop while the two variables are not equal and the conditionals should be inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, zufallszahl;
    zufallszahl = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    a = input.nextInt();
    while (a != zufallszahl) {
        if (a<zufallszahl)System.out.println("zu groß");
        else System.out.println("zu klein boy");
        System.out.println("Try again: ");
        a = input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("        B        I       N        G         O        ");
}
```

Your solution was not working because you can leave the loops even though the number is wrong.
In this way the user is stuck in the loop until he guesses the right number.

You can further reduce the code, though

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, zufallszahl=(int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    while ((a = input.nextInt()) != zufallszahl) 
        System.out.println(((a<zufallszahl)?"zu groß":"zu klein boy")+"\nTry again: ");
    System.out.println("        B        I       N        G         O        ");
}
```

Comment: Where are your braces?

Answer (score 2):

Your program is just stopping ...
Try this instead.

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int a, zufallszahl;
    zufallszahl = (int) (Math.random()*100 + 1);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    a = input.nextInt();
    while (a != zufallszahl){
        if (a < zufallszahl){
            System.out.println("zu klein boy");
        } else {
             System.out.println("zu groß");
        } 
        System.out.println("Try again: ");
        a = input.nextInt();    
    }
    System.out.println("        B        I       N        G         O        ");

}
```